# angularjs : iterate array with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating an array like the following:

```
var arr =[];
arr['key1'] = 'value1';
arr['key2'] = 'value2';
```

If is use this array in `ng-repeat` tag, it is not displaying anything. Is there any way to make it work?

```
<div data-ng-repeat='(key,value) in arr'>{{key}} - {{value}}</div>
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Use an object rather than an array. Or better, use an array containing objects with a key attribute and a value attribute. That way you'll have a deterministic order. Make sure the array is on the scope.

Comment: `ng-repeat` should work as shown. You are actually creating object though when using non-numeric keys

Comment: @charlietfl, added a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7RBEId2DWiRIvmfSPC9p?p=preview) here.

Comment: `$scope.myArr = {};` ... works fine as declaring object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go, is to creat plain object (instead of array)

```
// instead of creatin of an Array
// $scope.myArr = [];
// we just create plain object
$scope.myArr = {};
...
// here we just add properties (key/value)
$scope.myArr['attempt1'] = {};
...
// which is in this case same as this syntax
$scope.myArr.attempt1 = {};
```

Thee is [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xp949FrF45elSbsx9Zdl?p=preview)

Check more details what is behind for example here:

#### [Javascript: Understanding Objects vs Arrays and When to Use Them. [Part 1]](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

Your associative array is nothing but an object, as far as JavaScript is concerned. IMO Associative arrays and Objects are almost same.

Ex: Your `arr['key1'] = 'value1';` can be called as `console.log(arr.key1);`

To make your code work, you need to change the array declaration by removing `[]` and replacing with `{}` (Curly braces)

Like this `var arr = {};`